# handle multiple keycodes in same function

Tags: javascript

I'm new on java script. I'm trying to make this simple script to my html page.
My questions is how can I/ what's the correct way to add multiple keycodes to same function? Example. 17, 12, 71, 65. As you can see there's only keychar: 17

My current code:

```
function keyDown(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 17) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas ');
    canvas.innerHTML = '<img src="alert.png" /> '
    canvas.innerHTML += '<audio src="winxpalert.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"> '
  }
}

function keyUp(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 17) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas');
    canvas.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: try using switch

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: so I should put if + else if

Comment: @MoTiFy I don't mean to be rude, but this website isn't supposed to teach basic programming concepts. You need to look at JS tutorials and examples, do lots of research and try lots of things first. When you're still stuck, put the code you've tried into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make this work is using a [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). Check that link out to see how it works, it is pretty easy.

As an example:

```
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 17:
    var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas ');
    canvas.innerHTML = '<img src="alert.png" /> '
    canvas.innerHTML += '<audio src="winxpalert.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"> '
    break;

    case fooNumber:
    foo;
    break;
}});
```

To be honest I havn't tested the code, and I might've missed something since I havn't programmed keys in a while, but it should work. Obviously change fooNumber for the keyCode you wish and foo for the code you want to execute on that key press.

To make sure the keys are working, you can insert instead of foo something like

> alert("works")

And see if it is working.

Anything else, let me know.

Good luck! Cheers.